# drupal optimization

Tags: drupal, dreamhost

I am getting many 404 and 500 errors on my Drupal site, it is not very complex yet I am using Dreamhost and they are limiting my memory usage I think it is under 158MB, how do I find out what my memory limit is?  I do not have access to php.ini.  How do I optimize my database for performance or find the greatest memory hogs?

this is the error it is giving me

```
 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /home/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/includes/database.mysql.inc
```

on line 108 before i deleted a number of mmodules "tried to allocate xxxx bytes was much larger

Comment: did you ever get this fixed? I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could post some information on what specifically module wise you are running? Or what kind of operations your using?

You also should try taking a look at this [measurement of module memory usage](http://2bits.com/articles/measuring-memory-consumption-by-drupal-bootstrap-and-modules.html)

There are dozens of memory converters online if you need to convert to bytes/kilobytles to megabytes, but here is a [link](http://www.csgnetwork.com/memconv.html) to one if your lazy :)